# sensors-hal kernel module constantly restarting/reconecting and doing ramdumps

Tags: android

sensors-hal kernel module and sscrpcd daemon constantly restarting and doing ramdumps (20Mb each, every 3
sec), by doing so it is consuming all the internal flash drive space. It is going slowly kill the
flash drive by reaching its write limit. All the sensors are still working but they are freezing for 1
sec every 3 seconds (presumably during the sensors_hal restart).

The root cause could be a software bug induced by hardware malfunction. The phone was used
in a very damp environment for a couple of weeks but it was functioning properly.
I can live with jerky sensors (still it is not very pleasant) but at least I would like to stop it doing those ramdumps and killing sd memory.

I have already tried to do factory reset 2 times, tried to update to the newest MIUI 12 (Android 10 QKQ1.191117.002), tried to disable all sensors and logging using developer mode options and phone codes. Nothing
helps. Maybe some kernel boot parameter exists that controls this ramdump behaviour. There is some related Qualcomm code https://www.geek-share.com/detail/2689054095.html but its context is unknown.

```
08-06 13:35:59.414 838 22409 I sensors-hal: get_qmi_debug_flag:230, support_qmi_debug :
false
08-06 13:35:59.425 838 22409 I sensors-hal: ssc_conn_error_cb:526, after ssr, discovery of
accel took 1.250000 sec
08-06 13:35:59.426 838 22409 I sensors-hal: send_sensor_config_request:337, dt=accel,
asked batch_period_us : 2147483647 adjusted_us : 200000000
08-06 13:35:59.470 838 6732 I sensors-hal: get_qmi_debug_flag:230, support_qmi_debug :
false
08-06 13:35:59.479 838 2488 I sensors-hal: get_qmi_debug_flag:230, support_qmi_debug :
false
08-06 13:35:59.479 838 6732 I sensors-hal: ssc_conn_error_cb:526, after ssr, discovery of
pedometer took 1.250000 sec
08-06 13:35:59.490 838 2488 I sensors-hal: ssc_conn_error_cb:526, after ssr, discovery of
ambient_light took 1.250000 sec
08-06 13:35:59.508 838 3211 I sensors-hal: get_qmi_debug_flag:230, support_qmi_debug :
false
08-06 13:35:59.510 636 30189 I /vendor/bin/sscrpcd:
vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/apps_std_imp.c:722: Successfully opened
file /sys/class/backlight/panel0-backlight/brightness
08-06 13:35:59.776 838 3211 I sensors-hal: get_qmi_debug_flag:230, support_qmi_debug :
false
08-06 13:36:00.044 838 3211 I chatty : uid=1000(system) sensors@1.0-ser identical 1 line
08-06 13:36:00.310 838 3211 I sensors-hal: get_qmi_debug_flag:230, support_qmi_debug :
false
08-06 13:36:00.319 838 3211 I sensors-hal: ssc_conn_error_cb:526, after ssr, discovery of
sar_algo took 2.000000 sec
08-06 13:36:01.904 838 30198 E sensors-hal: handle_sns_client_event:51, sar_algo_event:
ts=1048061748766, event=0.000000


08-06 13:36:04.421 916 916 E /vendor/bin/sscrpcd:
vendor/qcom/proprietary/sensors-see/sscrpcd/src/sscrpcd.cpp:89:sscrpcd daemon will restart
after 25ms...
08-06 13:36:04.423 7392 7392 E subsystem_ramdump: subsystem ramdump start!
08-06 13:36:04.423 7392 7392 E subsystem_ramdump: subsystem generate_ramdump 1
08-06 13:36:04.423 7392 7392 I chatty : uid=0(root) subsystem_ramdu identical 7 lines
08-06 13:36:04.423 7392 7392 E subsystem_ramdump: subsystem generate_ramdump 1
08-06 13:36:04.423 4529 4529 E Diag_Lib: diag: In notify_handler, signal 18 received from
kernel, data is: 120010
08-06 13:36:04.423 4529 4529 E Diag_Lib: diag: DIAG_STATUS_CLOSED on
DIAG_CON_SENSORS
08-06 13:36:04.424 636 636 I /vendor/bin/sscrpcd:
vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_pm.c:113:
fastrpc_wake_lock_deinit done
08-06 13:36:04.424 636 636 I /vendor/bin/sscrpcd:
vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:2517:
fastrpc_apps_user_deinit done
08-06 13:36:04.424 636 636 E /vendor/bin/sscrpcd:
vendor/qcom/proprietary/sensors-see/sscrpcd/src/sscrpcd.cpp:89:sscrpcd daemon will restart
after 25ms...
08-06 13:36:04.425 7392 7392 E subsystem_ramdump: subsystem out file:
/sdcard/ramdump/ramdump_slpi_2020-08-06_13-36-04.elf
08-06 13:36:04.448 916 916 I /vendor/bin/sscrpcd:
vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys-intf/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:2572:
```